# Same axis order in two graphs

Tags: python, seaborn

I have this function:

```
def plot_stats_test(feature,label_rotation=False,horizontal_layout=True):

    temp = df_test_2[feature].value_counts()
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({feature: temp.index,'Количество клиентов': temp.values})

    # Расчет доли target=1 в категории
    cat_perc = df_train_2[[feature, Target']].groupby([feature],as_index=False).mean()

    if(horizontal_layout):
        fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12,6))
    else:
        fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(12,14))
    sns.set_color_codes("pastel")

    s = sns.barplot(ax=ax1, x = feature, y="Количество клиентов",data=df1)
    if(label_rotation):
        s.set_xticklabels(s.get_xticklabels(),rotation=90)
    plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=12)

    s = sns.barplot(ax=ax2, x = feature, y='Target', data=cat_perc, order=cat_perc[feature])

    if(label_rotation):
        s.set_xticklabels(s.get_xticklabels(),rotation=90)
    plt.ylabel('Доля продленных', fontsize=10)
    plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10)

    plt.show();
```

![enter image description here][1]

1. How to make the X axis signature on the right graph in the same order as the left graph?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - this includes a sample input and how you call your function. Please only ask one question - 2. is different from your original problem and should be asked in a separate question.

Comment: adding `sorted` to `s.get_xticklabels()`